# wdWord and wdExtend commands not working in Excel Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I've recently been trying to create a macro to automatically grab data from a word doc and place it in an excel sheet but I've run into a bit of an issue. After having the macro locate the particular piece of data I'm looking for, I need it to select the entire word before transferring it over. The issue is the commands I grabbed from a recorded Word macro don't seem to be working properly.

Excel seems to be interpreting the wdWord and wdExtend as undeclared variables, but im unsure how to get them to behave the way they do in Word.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

````
        WApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        WApp.Selection.Find.Execute "Crew Lead"
        WApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
        WApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        WApp.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend```
````

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly show the enumeration type:

```
WApp.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=WdUnits.wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=WdMovementType.wdExtend
```

OR

You can use the values of these enumerations. wdWord's value is 2 (see [WdUnits enumeration (Word)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdunits))

```
Name          Value         Description
wdWord        2             A word
```

while wdExtend's value is 1 [WdMovementType enumeration (Word)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdmovementtype)

```
Name          Value         Description
wdExtend      1             The end of the selection is extended to the end of the specified unit.
```

Your code will be:

```
WApp.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=2, Count:=1, Extend:=1
```